Prometheus Counter for time series aggregated data
I am using Prometheus Counter metrics, and each POST call, I increment the counter by custom amount. I am using Datadog to visualize the aggregated value by time interval, and I am having a trouble to query properly.
Say my data points are:
c = Counter('my_counter', 'Description of counter')

t0 (00:00): c.inc(10)
t1 (00:01): c.inc(15)
t2 (00:04): c.inc(12)
t3 (00:05): c.inc(3)
t4 (00:08): c.inc(10)

And if it's 00:10 currently, if I query

Past 10m, I should see 50 (t0+t1+...+t4)
Past 5m, I should see 13 (t3+t4)
Past 2m, I should see 10 (t4)

I've tried Time Series widget but when I look at the counter the number remains for few seconds, for instance 00:00:00 to 00:00:10 is 10.
If I want to achieve render such metrics graph data, should I use something different than Counter and increase(amount)?
I have tried different graph in datadog and also grafa query.
My problem is that I aggregate this counter over the time, but it seems the counter value stays for another X seconds. For instance, my request hits at 00:00:00 and I increased the counter by 10, then another 15 at 00:01:00 I expect to see it goes from 0 to 10 at 00:00:00 (or 00:00:05 in case of latency), then stays 10 until next request, 00:01:05, then 25 (10+15), but I see it goes 10 at 00:00:05 then drops to 0 at 00:00:15, then goes back from 0 to 15 at 00:01:05, then 15 to 0 at 00:01:15, etc.
I'd like to use this counter to visualize like a bar chart widget, show the aggregated value within the time interval.

Can you clarify what is the problem exactly? What do you get now, and what do you expect to get?

Also, I'm not familiar with datadog, but query increase(metric) is not valid in Prometheus: it must have range selector, and depending on that range results will vary.

@markalex Thank you for the reply! I updated/edited the post, but I want to get aggregated value in bar chart, so like a histogram where I can see the counter value aggregated in time interval (x-axis is time and y is counter value)
I feel like maybe I am using wrong metric type (counter) for this purpose?
Can you help me what do you mean for range selector?
